# Area of a region defined by an implicit function.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, implicit-function

I am trying to determine the area of this region:
$$
M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq2, x^4+x^3y^3\leq xy+y^4\}
$$

I know that $x^2+y^2\leq2$ represents a disk, but I have no idea of what $x^4+x^3y^3\leq xy+y^4$ represents, which is why I do not know what integration limits to choose (I was thinking of calculating this area with a double integral, but maybe this is not the best approach).

I have found a slightly similar problem on this site:
[Area enclosed by curve $f(x,y)$ defined implicitly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295786/area-enclosed-by-curve-fx-y-defined-implicitly). I have tried to obtain a known function out of $x^4+x^3y^3\leq xy+y^4$ by doing some transformations to the expression (like they do in the problem I have linked), but it has not worked out.

Could anyone give me any tips to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try factoring the expression... should look like $(x+y^3)(y-x^3)\geq 0$

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Thank you! That was really helpful, I have managed to solve the problem.